# The first day of school photos ["is" or "are"] coming

Tags: grammar, american-english

Which of these two sentences are correct?

- The first day of school photos is coming
- The first day of school photos are coming

Comment: As a parent in my second decade of "first day of school" photos (something my wife requires each year), it never would have occurred to me that this could be referring to the first day of [a multi-day] school [photo shoot]. Photos, in elementary and middle school, rarely take more than a day; even at my kids' High School (the largest in San Francisco), they only have multiple days because students are loathe to miss class to get their picture taken.  Also, it's usually (in my experience, in multiple districts) called, simply, _picture day_; one wouldn't normally call the event _school photos_.

Comment: Long story short, more context is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the sentences are correct, the context however of one differs from the other.

1. **The first day** *of school photos* is coming.

In this sentence, the **The first day** is the topic whereas *of school photos* is the prepositional phrase telling more about the topic.

2. *The first day of school* **photos** are coming.

In this sentence, the **photos** is the topic of the sentence whereas *The first day of school* is a noun phrase telling more about the topic.

Comment: +1: Whoever downvoted this answer fails to see that the 2nd interpretation here *may be correct* if "first day of school" is construed as a modifier of *photos*. (It must be said, however, that normally one would hyphenate such a modifier as "first-day-of-school photos," though that is certainly not a grammatical requirement.)

Answer (score 1):

The subject of a verb is not necessarily the closest preceding noun.

What is coming? The first day

*day* is the subject, and as a singular noun, takes *is* as the verb.

The photos are not coming; they're the object of the preposition *of*. The phrase *of school photos* tells you what kind of day.

If instead you actually mean the photos taken on the first day of school are coming, then *photos* is the subject and *first day of school* is an extended adjective modifier: *the first-day-of-school photos*, so to speak. In that case, plural subject, plural verb.

In spoken language, it's easy to differentiate the two; in writing, it's ambiguous. So if it’s really the photos you have in mind, recast the sentence.

Comment: Karl, please clean this up.  The normal interpretation of the sentence would be that the photos taken on the first day of school are coming.  It's quite a stretch to interpret it to mean that the first of the "day of school photos" is coming.

Comment: @HotLicks: Thank you for your opinion. It's one I don't share. It's somewhat like the optical illusion with the spinning ballerina. First day of school photos [being shot] or photos shot on the first day of school. Both are equally likely parsings.

Comment: [Zits comic for Friday, September 07, 2018](http://comicskingdom.com/zits/2018-09-07):  "Jeremy, we forgot to take our traditional 'first day of school' photo".